# How to prove that abs(sinx)=<abs(x) if X is in IR?

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry

Give me hints so I can figure it out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. What is IR? Please be precise and tell the reader what you already tried

Comment: What's your definition of sinx? And IR?

Comment: Hi, please show your initial attempts and work, also please use proper notation